# Reset schema oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm running systemtest that updates a oracle schema. I need to reset the whole scheme between runs.

Is there an easy way to do this in oracle 12. I have looked at flashback but it doesn't seem to be the right way to go.

Comment: You can flashback a table or the whole database, but not a schema. If rewinding the whole database to an earlier state is acceptable, flashback is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you looked at flashback queries, what you need are restore points.

1. Create a guaranteed restore point before starting test
2. Perform test, measure, save results
3. startup mount the db, flashback database to restore point
4. drop and re-create guaranteed restore point.
5. lather. rinse. repeat

It really doesn't get easier than that. I do it multiple times a week and have essentially reduced it to a small script and keep doing this against my dev db.